# pointers to member functions with boost::variant

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, casting

I m trying to define a "generic" pointer to a member function that could be used to access various member functions within a particular class as follows:

```
class Security{
    inline std::vector<double> member_function(const std::string &input_data_string){ return ... a vector<double>....;};
    };
```

I'm defining a generic pointer to a member function that could be used to access "OTHER" functions as well with different return types as well as  different type parameters, by using boost::variant.

```
typedef boost::variant<std::string,double, std::vector<double>, std::vector<std::string>>  (Security::*ptr_sec_fn)(boost::variant<std::string,double, std::vector<double>, std::vector<std::string>> );
```

Then assigning the pointer to the member function

```
    ptr_sec_fn=&Security::member_function;
```

This is the error that i'm getting:

```
cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty> (__thiscall Security::* )(const std::string &)' to 'boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2,T3> (__thiscall Security::* )(boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2,T3>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::string,
1>              T1=double,
1>              T2=std::vector<double>,
1>              T3=std::vector<std::string>
1>          ]
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Could you please help me identify what i'm doing wrong here? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you considered using `boost::function` or `std::function` instead?

Comment: Also look at `boost::bind` and `boost::phoenix::bind`

Answer (score 0):

This can not work this way. Someone has to do the conversion from the vector to the variant type, and your function can't do it (because it returns a vector, and that's all it knows about) and the code creating the pointer can't do it either (because it cannot create a function on the fly).

On the other hand, you might want to re-think your design anyway. Why do you need a such generic function pointer anyway? Can it be specified more concretely? A good design shows itself through clear types, because the types show the programmer more exactly what data are required than any documentation does.

Comment: I'm doing this because i dont want to redefine the pointer each time i want to call a different memeber function although each time i will call the function i know its return type. How can i do the conversion if i'm to call the function through the pointer something like: ptr_sec_fn=&(boost::get<std::vector<double>>Security::member_function).. not sure if this is a valid syntax!

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Security::member_function` is `std::vector<Ty> (_thiscall Security::* )(const std::string &)` which is completely different from the type of the pointer you're trying to assign it to. This is not allowed. You can only assign member functions that take and return that variant to a member function pointer of that type.

If this assignment worked, then code trying to call your member function pointer would pass a variant to the function, and the function would be broken because it expects a string. There's not enough information anywhere for anybody to know that someone needs to somehow get a string out of your variant. And even if all that did work, when the function returns a vector someone needs to know that the vector needs to be used to construct a variant. That would have to be done at the call site, but the call site doesn't even know a vector is being returned. The fact that you know what type is being returned isn't enough, the compiler has to know it. And the fact that you know the type indicates that you shouldn't be using a catch-all type in the first place. You should just use the correct type.

If you have a bunch of overloaded functions that take and return different types, you're not going to be able to have a single member function pointer that can point to any of those overloads. Trying to do this just completely ignores the type safety in C++. So you'll have to think of a type safe way to do what you want.

We'd need more info on what your goal is to help you find a way to do it, but what you're currently attempting is never going to work.